# How to access child nodes of a root element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to access child nodes of a root element but I am unable to do so as the elements that come back are all "undefined" - including the array that is returned.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function dothis()
        {
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("body").parentNode.childNodes;
        alert(elements.length);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="dothis();">
    <p>Welcome</p>
    <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PrPPM/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a `NodeList` (according to the spec. In some browsers e.g. Firefox I think it returns an `HTMLCollection`). In any case, what it returns is an array-like object. You need to access the element at a specific index:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].parentNode.childNodes;
```